# Se vacía la propiedad del modelo en cada POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tengo este ViewModel:

```
 public class ComprasCreateModel
    {

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        public int JuegoId { get; set; }

        public List<DetalleCompra> DetalleCompra { get; set; }


        public ComprasCreateModel()
        {
            DetalleCompra = new List<DetalleCompra>(); // instanciamos la propiedad para que no sea null y podamos acceder a sus propiedades
        }
     }
```

Este Model (tabla en la base de datos):

```
public class DetalleCompra
    {

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int CompraId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int JuegoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Juego Juego { get; set; }


        public int Cantidad { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public int SubTotal { get; set; }

    }
```

y este controlador:

```
// POST: Compras/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ComprasCreateModel compra, string submitButton)
        {


            if (submitButton == "Agregar al Carro de Compras")
            {
DetalleCompra detalle = new DetalleCompra
                        {
                            Juego = juego,
                            Cantidad = compra.Cantidad,
                            SubTotal = juego.Precio * compra.Cantidad
                        };

                        compra.DetalleCompra.Add(detalle);

           return View(compra);
 }
else if (submitButton == "Generar Compra")
{

// acá crearé la compra una vez listado todos los productos en compra.DetalleCompra()

}

}
```

Y sucede que agrego la primera vez sin problemas un producto a compra.DetalleCompra(), y devuelve la Vista donde se muestra en una tabla el listado de productos y el formulario para seguir buscando y agregando productos.

Pero cuando le doy click nuevamente a "Agregar al Carro de Compras", el modelo "compra" entra al controlador con los datos de ClienteId y JuegoId correctos, pero la lista DetalleCompra entra vacía.

Por lo que siempre tengo un único producto en DetalleCompra.

¿Que sucederá?

Si creen necesario subo la Vista. Pero simplemente lo que hace es poner un formulario para que se le envíe el modelo ComprasCreateModel.

edit:

```
@model TiendaJuegos.ViewModels.ComprasCreateModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registro";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    TempData.Keep("Clientes");
    TempData.Keep("Juegos");
}

<h3>Agregue juegos al Carro de Compras:</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClienteId", (SelectList)TempData["Clientes"], new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Juego", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("JuegoId", (SelectList)TempData["Juegos"], new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("dropError", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cantidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "1", @id = "txtCantidad" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("cantidadError", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Agregar al Carro de Compras" class="btn btn-default" name="submitButton" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <hr />

    @if (Model != null && Model.DetalleCompra != null && Model.DetalleCompra.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table">

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Nombre del Juego
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Cantidad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SubTotal
                    </th>

                </tr>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DetalleCompra.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DetalleCompra[i].Juego.Nombre)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DetalleCompra[i].Cantidad)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DetalleCompra[i].SubTotal)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                <tr>

                    <th>
                        -
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        -
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        TOTAL A PAGAR: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.PrecioTotal)
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Crear Compra" class="btn btn-default" name="submitButton" />
            </div>
        </div>

    }


</div>
}
```

Comment: Subí un snippet de la vista

Comment: si agregas un producto al detalle de compra y puedes visualizarlo, esto donde lo persistes? o sea que hace compra.DetalleCompra()? porque podrias mantener la lista en Session y asi no necesitas que en el post de Create te llegue desde el html, sino que lo tendrias en el servidor

Comment: lo que hago en la Vista Create.html es ir mostrando una Tabla con los productos agregados (es decir, el carro de compras digamos). Eso lo hago haciendo un for en la lista DetalleCompra, pero como solamente me guarda un elemento siempre entonces esa Table muestra solamente el ultimo producto agregado.

Una vez que se hace click en el botón "Generar compra" mi intención es guardar en la base de datos una compra que tendrá la lista DetalleCompra como propiedad.

Comment: Entiendo que podría usar Session, podría ser una solución, pero tengo un ejemplo analogo a lo que intento hacer y no usa Session, simplemente intenta hacer lo que hago yo:

El modelo pasa al controller, se le agrega un item a la propiedad DetalleCompra del modelo y se llama de nuevo a la Vista pasandole ese modelo: return View(compra).

Luego, se supone que el modelo queda en la Vista, para ser modificado, en este caso indicando un JuegoId diferente, para luego mandarlo al controlador Create nuevamente y agregar allí ese juego nuevo.

Comment: Aún así lo pueda solucionar con Session, me interesa saber por qué no funciona lo que quiero hacer, teniendo un ejemplo hace lo mismo sin usar Session.

Además que entendería mejor la lógica de todo esto.

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicacion original mostrando el codigo de la Vista

Comment: Edu la función `public ActionResult Create(ComprasCreateModel compra, string submitButton)` que retorna en caso de estar agregando un item?

Comment: Ah, perdón, se me olvidó eso. Lo que devuelve es un return View(compra);

Comment: alguien me da una mano? :/